# Change radius for a single point on Heatmap?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, heatmap

Here is how you create Heatmap layer in Google Maps Api:

```
var data = [
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4072, 24.7053),weight:0.8},
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4372, 24.7473),weight: 1},
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4372, 24.7493),weight:0.8},
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.483428, 24.841709),weight: 0.6},
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.483256, 24.846666),weight: 0.2},
        {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.409425, 27.278345),weight: 0.3}
    ];

heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: data,
    radius: 10
});
```

As you can see, you have to specify radius in Heatmap config.
**But how can I specify different radius for a single source (point) on the Heatmap?**

Comment: Can you make different "data" array and have assign it different radius?

Comment: that won't work, because originally it expects `radius` to be in the heatmap config

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory you could make multiple heatmap layers 
https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/issues/96#issuecomment-272202758

```
var data1 = [
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4072, 24.7053),weight:0.8},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4372, 24.7473),weight: 1},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4372, 24.7493),weight:0.8},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.483428, 24.841709),weight: 0.6},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.483256, 24.846666),weight: 0.2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.409425, 27.278345),weight: 0.3}
];
```

heatmap1 = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer1({
    data: data1,
    radius: 10
});

```
var data2 = [
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4072, 24.7053),weight:0.8},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4372, 24.7473),weight: 1},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4372, 24.7493),weight:0.8},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.483428, 24.841709),weight: 0.6},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.483256, 24.846666),weight: 0.2},
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.409425, 27.278345),weight: 0.3}
];
```

heatmap2 = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer2({
    data: data2,
    radius: 3
});

Comment: I guess que question its to change the radius from each point, not just creating a tons and tons of maps just for that...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove the radius from the config!

Example:

```
var heatMapData = [
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), weight: 0.5},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443), weight: 2}
];

heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatMapData
});
```

You can find how to customize the heatmap layers  > [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer#customize_a_heatmap_layer) <